# Laravel Login stopped working, plus new redirect statement started showing up

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've noticed a redirect statement showing up recently, today and yesterday in my project, every time the page changes, like when logging in or submitting a form.

I then decided to refresh my database using *artisan migrate:refresh --seed* and I can't even login. I just get a redirect message to the /members/ then back to /login

Anyone come across this before?

My Auth Code :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Socialite;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/members';
    protected $socialite;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Socialite $socialite)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        // populate the md5 attribute
        $user->md5 = md5($user->id);
        $user->save();


        return $user;
    }



     public function getSocialAuth($provider=null)
       {
           if(!config("services.$provider")) abort('404'); //just to handle providers that doesn't exist

           return $this->socialite->with($provider)->redirect();
       }


       public function getSocialAuthCallback($provider=null)
       {
          if($user = $this->socialite->with($provider)->user()){
             dd($user);
          }else{
             return 'something went wrong';
          }
       }
}
```

note: i'm only using the md5 as a unique value for the user temporarily.

update:
after clearing my cookies, when trying to login now I don't even get to the redirect I just get the below error message.

TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

update:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

update: I've changed to a the session config to use the database, and the error still persists.

Comment: Did you change the application key? Is the user seed data random or something you've specified manually? Your question is pretty broad, you've added no code so it's really hard to guess where the problem may originate. At least post the code relevant to the login process.

Comment: No i've changed nothing relating to the laravel code, just my code. Im sorry i didn't know what would be relevant to the problem. The seed data is static. What class do you want me to post?

Comment: I see you're using Socialite as a login option (at least you have code for it). What exactly is not working anymore: the social login and/or the regular user/pass login?

Comment: The standard login

Comment: Please post your login `auth.login` view.

Comment: Done mate, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You're oAuth (Socialite) callback url's are probably failing csrf check.
Add them to the `$except` array in the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
// app/Http/Middelware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

....
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'oauth/twitter/callback',
        'oauth/linkedin/callback',
        'oauth/facebook/callback'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Still happening, i'm not trying to login via social lite just the standard laravel login